# PDO prepared statement returns empty set, Query works fine

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have below PDO function that executes a Mysql query. Its working correctly for all queries.

```
public function run($sql, array $params = NULL) {

  $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

  if (!is_null($params)) {

    foreach ($params as $key) {

      $statement->bindParam(":n", $key);

    }

  }

  $statement->execute();

  return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

}
```

However when i run the below query its returns an empty set

```
$variation = $query->run(
  "SELECT url, title, sale_price
  FROM product
  where category_id = :n
  and url != :n",
  [ $data[0]->category_id, $filePathArray[1] ]
);
```

Its works when i run the query manually in mysql client.

I tried type casting the category id but no joy:

```
(int)$data[0]->category_id
```

(since it was passing a string as opposed to Integer)

Here is the var_dump of $params from within the run function

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> int(1) 
  [1]=> string(21) "light-resistance-band" 
}
```

Comment: You can't reuse placeholders in a single query.

Comment: You're using named placeholders, with the name `:n` used twice, and you're binding two different values to `:n`. How's that supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add ***different named place-holder to bind corresponding values***(not identical)

```
$variation = $query->run(
  "SELECT url, title, sale_price
  FROM product
  where category_id = :n
  and url != :n1",
  [ ':n'=>$data[0]->category_id, ':n1'=>$filePathArray[1] ]
);
```

Comment: makes sense i'll do that

Comment: @BennyThadikaran  you can address me the link. If i have time i will answer or some-one will answer for-sure

Answer (score 0):

You can custommize your function checking the type of `$key` and bindParam like this:

```
 public function run($sql, array $params = NULL) {

  $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

  if (!is_null($params)) {

    foreach ($params as $key=>$value) {
        $statement->bindParam(":".$key, $value);
    }

  }

  $statement->execute();

  return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Goms, but this limits the params to 2. Please see my edit. P.S - I didn't down vote your answer.

Comment: that doesn't work either :(. Still returns an empty set. Btw ":"$key need to be ":$key". I could just write a separate function for this but just wondering whats wrong.