# PDO MySql function to accept multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have below PDO function that executes a Mysql query.

```
public function run($sql, array $params = NULL) {

  $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

  if (!is_null($params)) {

    foreach ($params as $key) {

      $statement->bindParam(":n", $key);

    }

  }

  $statement->execute();

  return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

}
```

This only works with single parameters (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223027/pdo-prepared-statement-returns-empty-set-query-works-fine/48223181?noredirect=1#comment83430624_48223181))

So i tried modifying the foreach in the function to

```
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {

  $statement->bindParam($key, $value);

}
```

I run the query as

```
$variation = $query->run(
  "SELECT url, title, sale_price
  FROM product
  where category_id = :category
  and url != :url",
  [ ":category" => $data[0]->category_id, ":url" => $filePathArray[1] ]
);
```

It returns an empty set.

Comment: Why woud you do that when you can simply pass the array of parameters to `$statement->execute()`?

Comment: @rlanvin . with `bindParam()` , you can specify the type(int, string)etc, which is the third parameter.

Comment: @Akintunde007 it's not used here though...

Comment: @rlanvin . yes i see that. I was just providing information ;)

Comment: I read elsewhere bindparam prevents sql injection. Is that the same with execute()? Thats the only reason for me to use bindparam. Is specifying  the type necessary?

Comment: @rlanvin your answer works. Its better cause i can get rid of foreach statement. I think it should also prevents injection since passing additional values in the array would result in the statement failing.

Comment: @rlanvin You can go ahead and answer it. I'll select it as the best answer

Comment: Done! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is not necessary. You can pass the array of parameters directly to `$statement->execute()` as explained [in the documentation for PDOStatement::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

It is as safe as using `bindParam()`, it protects against SQL injection just the same.

The only downside is that you cannot specify the type of each parameter, but that isn't necessary in most cases, and in this example you were not using it anyway so you won't loose anything.